# Custom Controls Not Visible in XAML After Migrating to .NET 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, .net-8.0

I recently migrated my project from .NET 4.8.1 to .NET 8. In my project, I have a custom control implemented in a `Themes.Generic.xaml` ResourceDictionary, and the C# implementation which contains the DependencyProperties is in the `MyProject.CustomControls` namespace.

After the migration, my custom controls are not visible in XAML. They appear as empty rectangles with zero width. If I manually expand the widths, I get empty rectangles.

Here is my `Generic.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:materialdesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FloatingLabelComboBox">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControls.FloatingLabelComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControls.FloatingLabelComboBox}">
                    <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                        <Label Content="{TemplateBinding LabelText}"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding LabelForeground}"
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding LabelFontSize}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                               Margin="-5 0 0 0" 
                        />

                        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
                                  ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                                  SelectedItem="{TemplateBinding SelectedItem}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="{TemplateBinding SelectedValuePath}"
                                  SelectedValue="{TemplateBinding SelectedValue}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="{TemplateBinding DisplayMemberPath}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  Width="Auto"
                                  Height="Auto"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.IsFloating="False"
                                  materialdesign:ColorZoneAssist.Mode="Dark"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.HintOpacity="0.10"
                                  materialdesign:HintAssist.FontFamily="Century Gothic"
                                  Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">

                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And Here is C# implementation which contains the DependencyProperties:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace FloatingLabelComboBox.CustomControls
{
    public class FloatingLabelComboBox : Control
    {
        static FloatingLabelComboBox()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata("LabelText"));

        public string LabelText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelForegroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelForeground", typeof(Brush), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFD6931B"))));

        public Brush LabelForeground
        {
            get { return (Brush)GetValue(LabelForegroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelForegroundProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelFontSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("LabelFontSize", typeof(double), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(10.0));

        public double LabelFontSize
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(LabelFontSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LabelFontSizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValuePathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValuePath", typeof(string), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string SelectedValuePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedValuePathProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public object SelectedValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberPathProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(FloatingLabelComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public string DisplayMemberPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayMemberPathProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the following:

- The namespace of the custom control is correctly declared in the XAML
  file.
- The DefaultStyleKeyProperty is overridden in the static constructor
  of the custom control class.
- The AssemblyInfo.cs file contains the necessary entry.
- The solution has been rebuilt.

The build action for the XAML files is “Page”, and for the C# files, it’s “C# compiler”. In .NET 4.8.1, the build action was “Compile”.

[Here is the github repository to the full project](https://github.com/MeshkaM/FloatingLabelComboBox/tree/master/FloatingLabelComboBoxCore), Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `ThemeInfo` attribute to your .NET 8 assembly:

```
using System.Windows;

[assembly: ThemeInfo(
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.None,
    ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly
)]
```

Comment: OK in my Test PC which is the One hosting the github repos and the example i provided, i found that the file "AssemblyInfo.cs" was missing, I added that and it worked, But in my Development PC i found that  "AssemblyInfo.cs" was there with the Content you provided but the problem still persist, What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ooh!, I found the problem  `x:Key="MyCustomControl"` in Generic.xaml. After deleting that everything worked nicely.